# I have to make an API where I can return orders (product name) placed by a customer using customer Id?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

In `sales_order` table product name field  is not there but i have to fetch that too. How to fetch the product name ordered by a customer using customer ID?

Comment: get customer ordered order and also order items Right?

Comment: Grammatically speaking, the title shouldn't have a question mark at the end.

Answer (score 4):

You can try below:

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
```

If you need more details from order you can review below post.

http://www.codextblog.com/code-snippet/get-order-information-from-order-id-in-magento-2/

Comment: $order->getAllItems(): it will return an array right?......with all column name as index of array.....

Comment: can i use getData() function inplace of getAllItems()?   will that mean the same?

Comment: You cant use `getData` here, You can use `var_dump` to see what data are in object and you can use those.

Comment: can you please tell me what does getData function do? and what does it return?

Answer (score 3):

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    ....
}

//and use in required method as:

$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
       echo $item->getName()); // to print all ordered products name
}
```

Comment: $this->orderRepository->get($orderId): what does this return ?

Comment: it returns a collection and inside that lot of function ; you can try **print_r(get_class_methods($order)); die;** to view that and getAllItems() provides all items purchased with that order_id entered